# BatchNorm and Reshuffle train images after each epoch

Tags: caffe, conv-neural-network

The recommended way of using BatchNorm is to reshuffle the training imageset between each epoch, so that a given image does not fall in a mini-batch with the same images on each pass.

How do you achieve that with Caffe?

Comment: To my understanding, in caffe you would have to write a python or c++ training interface that supports it. There is no convenient option. I suggest bailing to tensorflow at the earliest available opportunity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the ImageData Layer as your input, set "shuffle" to `true`.

For example, if you have:

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "ImageData"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  transform_param {
    mirror: false
    crop_size: 227
    mean_file: "data/ilsvrc12/imagenet_mean.binaryproto"
  }
  image_data_param {
    source: "examples/_temp/file_list.txt"
    batch_size: 50
    new_height: 256
    new_width: 256
  }
}
```

Just add:

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "ImageData"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  transform_param {
    mirror: false
    crop_size: 227
    mean_file: "data/ilsvrc12/imagenet_mean.binaryproto"
  }
  image_data_param {
    source: "examples/_temp/file_list.txt"
    batch_size: 50
    new_height: 256
    new_width: 256
    shuffle: true
  }
}
```

For documentation, see:

- http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers.html#images
- https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L770

You can also find the source code here:

- https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/image_data_layer.cpp

Of particular interest is the code within the function `load_batch` which re-shuffles the data at the end of each epoch:

```
lines_id_++;
if (lines_id_ >= lines_size) {
  // We have reached the end. Restart from the first.
  DLOG(INFO) << "Restarting data prefetching from start.";
  lines_id_ = 0;
  if (this->layer_param_.image_data_param().shuffle()) {
    ShuffleImages();
  }
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly this performs the shuffle once (at start) and on the whole set. I am looking for a way to force a reshuffle within each mini-batch, once on every pass.

Comment: This re-shuffles the data at the end of each epoch, so that the mini-batches will have different examples each epoch. Isn't that what you want? I'm not sure what you mean about reshuffling within each mini-batch. I've added to my answer to hopefully make it clearer.